# Part of speech of "brief" and "short" in the phrases "in brief" and "in short"

Tags: adjectives, prepositional-phrases, prepositional-objects

The phrases "in brief" and "in short" function as adverbs, but as what part of speech do "brief" and "short" function in these phrases? "Brief" stands alone as both a noun and adjective and could be seen as either in the phrase (i.e. preposition "in" + noun/adjective "brief"), but "short" in the meaning used by the phrase only occurs as an adjective. Are these two phrases exceptional in that an adjective is the object of the preposition (discounting constructions such as, "Do you have this in blue?")? Are they simply "fixed" phrases that can't be broken down into their constituents?

Comment: _Brief_ is a predicate adjective in _Be brief_. _In short_ (a fixed phrase, which means it's stuck together and used as a unit, like a Tinkertoy® construction left out in the rain) is ... um ... short for "in a short summation/conclusion", with emphasis on the **short** part. Since it's all that's left of a noun phrase, and since it's the object of a preposition, it's a noun. If it matters; it's idiomatic, like I said.

Comment: May be worth noting other similar phrases, as "in sum," "in summary," "in total," "in all," et cetera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think grammarians are going to have various opinions, but the *Oxford English Dictionary* thinks these are both nouns. Or, more precisely, they are adjectives used as "absolute" constructions which omit the noun they reference implicitly, somewhat similarly to a process where we use an adjective as a substantive, like referring to *the weak* when we mean *the weak [people]*.

There are all sorts of uses in English (and other languages) where we just use AdjectiveX to mean AdjectiveX [things, people, etc.], and when such uses become idiomatic, the adjective is effectively converted into a noun.  Combining such an adjective with a preposition isn't an exception in English either, though these idioms are a little unusual in that such absolute constructions often have *the* before the adjective to mark it as a noun.

Anyhow, here are some excerpts from the definitions and related senses in the *OED*.

For *in brief*:

> n.
>
> a. ***in brief***: in few words, shortly, concisely. With ellipsis of
>   ‘to speak’: In short, to sum up.
>
> †b. ***the brief***, used *absol.* like
>   *the short*. *Obs.*

The (a) usage has an earliest citation of 1423, which is roughly the same time when "brief" first came to be used as an adjective in English.  (Notably, the use of "brief" as a noun in the sense of a formal letter, dispatch, or note has citations at least a century earlier; whether there's a connection between this idiom and the slightly older noun is a question I leave to the professional etymologists.  The *OED* seems to think "no.")

For *in short*:

> n.
>
> I. The neuter adj. used *absol.*
>
> 1. With prepositions, forming adv. phrases.
>
>    a. ***in short*** (also *Sc.* †***at short***): briefly, concisely.
>      From the 18th c. onwards used only as parenthetical phrase,
>      introducing or accompanying  a summary statement of what has been
>      previously said. †***in short and plain***: briefly and plainly.
>
>    †b. ***in short*** (? also *Sc.* ***at short***): in a short time,
>      quickly. *Obs.*
>
>    c. ***for short***: as an abbreviation.
> 2. ***the short***: the total, the result, upshot; a brief summing up of something which has been previously explained in full. Now only
>      *dial*. (Cf. *the long and the short of (it, etc.)* ...) †***short is***: ‘to speak briefly’, ‘the short of the matter is’.
> 3. Phr. ***to draw short and long*** : to draw lots by means of straws, etc. of different lengths.

The phrase *in short and plain* dates at least back to Chaucer, but the *OED* has the first citations of *at short* and *in short* in the first sense in the 1500s.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that these are abbreviated phrases, e.g. *in brief* is short for something like *in brief terms*. So *brief* is an adjective, but the word it modifies has been elided.

Comment: And abbreviated briefs are *Speedos* (noun).

Comment: @JimReynolds Not *Speedoes* or *Speedi?*

Comment: @BrianDonovan Speedopodes.

Comment: @Mortimer _Speedum_

Comment: In Israel they'd be _Speedim_, but I guess that's OT for ELU.

Answer (score 2):

*In short* is an idiom, and idioms cannot be broken down to into their constituents.

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/short)

[image]

The same goes for [in brief](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/brief)

[image]